# django first word of a char field

Tags: django, postgresql

My model in django has a character field with maximum length 500 character. I'm working with a PostgreSQL database:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
 
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def first_word(self):
        return self.message.split(" ")[0]
```

I'm interested to evaluate first word of each message and do some aggregation. First word of each message could vary in length thus I can't use Left, Right or Substr database functions:

```
queryset = Chat.objects.annotate(command=F("first_word")).values("command")
            .annotate(counts=Count("command"))
            .order_by("-counts")
```

Obviously my queryset is not working because I can't call model methods in database query. However is there a way I can do this by using some other database functions?